# "Object reference not set" from .resx in Visual Studio 2019 & 2022, .Net 5 WinForms project when .resx contains System.Drawing.Point

Tags: visual-studio, resx

I have inherited a WinForms project that I have more or less successfully upgraded to .Net Core.  One irritation is that I cannot open the .resx files in Visual Studio.  It gives "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

[image]

The .resx is quite long but what I've noticed is that I need to remove all xml tags which reference System.Drawing.Primitives.

```
  <data name="splitContainer1.Location" type="System.Drawing.Point, System.Drawing.Primitives">
    <value>0, 0</value>
  </data>
```

I don't have System.Drawing.Primitives referenced.  I did try adding a nuget package but it didn't help.  The rest of the program is working fine and all controls on forms are appearing in correct location.

What is the problem with System.Drawing.Primitives?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by doing search/replace
Search For: System.Drawing.Primitives
Replace With: System.Drawing